# Select sub-list with highest integer value in a specified position

Tags: python, max, nested-lists

I have a nested list:

```
nested_list = [['a', 3], ['a', 1], ['a', 5]]
```

How do I iterate over this list, select the sublist with the max integer value?

```
holder = []

for entry in nested_list:
    tmp = sublist with max entry[2] value
    holder.append(tmp)
```

I am stuck on coding the second line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try:

```
max(nested_list, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

or

```
import operator

max(nested_list, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

If the first item will always be `'a'`, you can just do

```
max(nested_list)
```

If you're willing to dive into some type checking and you want to do this for arbitrary sublists (Of one level only. something like [12, 'a', 12, 42, 'b']), you can do something like.

```
import numbers

max(nested_list, key=lambda x: max(i for i in x 
                                   if isinstance(i, numbers.Integral)))
```

In any case, if you're not sure that the elements of `nested_list` are in fact lists, you can do

```
import collections

max((s for s in nested_list 
     if isinstance(s, collections.Sequence)), 
    key=some_key_function)
```

and just pass it a key function of your own devising or one of the other ones in this answer.

In terms of the `lambda x: x[1]` vs. `operator.itemgetter(1)` question, I would profile. In princible, `itemgetter` should be the one right way but I've seen `operator` solutions get outperformed by lambda function do to 'bugs' (I use the term loosely, the code still works) in `operator`. My preference would be for `itemgetter` if performance doesn't matter (and probably if it does) but some people like to avoid the extra `import`.

Comment: I had to resort to my python books to figure out your solution. So, not only do I now have a solution, I understand a little more python. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
biggest = nested_list[0]

for entry in nested_list:
    if entry[1] > biggest[1]:
        biggest = entry
```

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, Care to elaborate?  The version with max(...) is a little more elegant, but the OP seems to be someone who is new to the language, and I wouldn't expect them to dive into lambda expressions before they understand for loops.

Answer (score 1):

If the list is as simple as you suggest:

```
>>> nested_list = [['a', 3], ['a', 1], ['a', 5], ['a',2]]
>>> k = sorted(nested_list)
>>> k[-1]
['a', 5]
>>>
```

Comment: If the first position of the inner lists has the same value, sure. Otherwise, no.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams : Yes, I know this is a very simplistic answer. The solution can become convoluted based on the scope of inputs. :)