# How to find a list in a list of lists where the first element is the greatest?

Tags: python, list, numpy, max

I have a list of lists like this:

```
a = [[15, 'bane', 'smth'], [13, 'qwe', 'qweqw'], ...]
```

I need to check for the first element and output the list with the greatest first element.

In this case:

```
[15, 'bane', 'smth']
```

I tried using `amax` from NumPy, but I only need to get the maximum based on the first element and that doesn't work

```
a = np.amax(a, axis=0)
```

I get the error

```
cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

because the other elements are strings I suppose. Is there any other method that I can use for this purpose?

Comment: More general question: [Select sub-list with highest integer value in a specified position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4299422/7851470)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can just use the regular old `max` function, since iterables are compared based on their first element.

```
a = max(a)
```

Comment: In the case where there are `int` or `float` dtypes in the first and second elements the previous answer won't give what the OP wants.

Comment: They're compared lexicographically on all the elements, but the first element has highest precedence.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `key` parameter in the `max` function to specify what to use for sorting.  As it is the first item, however, simply `max(a)` should suffice.

```
>>> max(a, key=lambda sublist: sublist[0])
[15, 'bane', 'smth']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just do `max(map(lambda x: x[0], a))` to first select the first element of arrays then take the max

Comment: That would return only the value, not the list.